# Returning true and a value from class function

Tags: python

In my project i return `True` from a function within my class, when looking over the code i need to return `True` plus a ***URL value*** but i am coming in to issues, i would instanciate the class like:

```
if Engine(driver).mode_login_and_post(driver, "http://" + xml_site_name.get_text() + "/wp-login.php", s_user, s_pass, xml_content_title.get_text(), body_with_html, SLEEP, captcha, verify=False) == True:
run more code once true is returned ...
looking to get the returned value of a url here is possible ...
```

`Engine` is the class i have instantiated, the way it is now this works fine, i'm getting back `True` so i continue with the code execution, is there a way to get back `True` plus another value (in this case a URL) to use in the rest of the code execution? i cannot think of  away to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could return a tuple: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple

Comment: Why do you return a success indicator plus a value? Why not return a value on success, and raise an exception on failure?

Comment: What would a return value of `False` mean? Most likely, you don't want to return a boolean at all: return the URL, and raise an exception if there is no valid URL to return.

Comment: I need to return a value aswell, the reason being is that function produces a URL i need access too.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is definitely applicable; I'll refrain from using my dupe hammer though as this appears to be an XY problem and it answers Y, not X.

Comment: @willerson Yes, but what does `True` tell you that a valid URL doesn't already tell you? Is `(False, <valid URL)` a possible return value? If not, you don't need the boolean at all.

Comment: What happens in that function is it posts on my website, once posted i collect the posted url like: http://example.com/page-url save it to a .txt file, once the ```True``` is send back i then read that .txt file to get the URL (which works) but i thought it best to return the URL (if possible) from the function aswell as the ```True``` which seemed cleaner, so i can do: (True, 'http://example.com/posted-url') from the function eh? the issue is getting the URL content once returned, am i over complicating this? it wouldn't be the first time lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return two values, but you can return a tuple or a list and unpack it after the call.

Example:

```
def select_choice():
    x = 5
    y = 1
    return x,y  # or [x, y]

x_, y_ = select_choice()
print (x_) # 5
print (y_) # 1
```

On line `return x,y` means creating a tuple.